# Laravel save previous url and redirect after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my routes.php I have these routes:

```
Route::group(["middleware" => "isValidAddress"], function() {
Route::group(["middleware" => "isNotAuth"], function() {

    // Password
    Route::group(["prefix" => "password"], function () {
        Route::get("/", "PasswordController@getIndice");

        // Gestione Password
        Route::match(["GET", "POST"], "password", "PasswordController@getPasswords");
        // Nuovo
        Route::get("password/nuovo", "PasswordController@getInsertPassword");
        Route::post("password/nuovo", "PasswordController@postInsertPassword");
        // Modifica
        Route::get("password/modifica/{idPWD}", ["as" => "getPassword", "uses" => "PasswordController@getUpdatePassword"]);
        Route::post("password/modifica/{idPWD}", "PasswordController@postUpdatePassword");
        // Elimina
        Route::post("password/elimina", "PasswordController@deletePassword");

        // Importazione password da Vtiger
        Route::match(["GET", "POST"], "importazione", "PasswordController@importazionePassword");

        // Genera una password random
        Route::post("genera", "PasswordController@generaPassword");
        // Visualizza la password decriptata
        Route::post("visualizza", "PasswordController@visualizzaPassword");
    });
```

The middleware "isValidAddress" check if the IP of the client is authorize to access, while the middleware isNotAuth redirect user if he isn't authenticate:

```
    class isNotAuth {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        // Se non è loggato lo reinderizzo alla pagina di login
        if (!$request->session()->get("operatore")) {
            // Mi salvo in sessione la pagina in cui si stava tentando di accedere prima di effettuare la login
            $request->session()->put("URL_PWD", $request->getUri());
            return redirect("login");
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

It also save in session the page that user wanted to visit previous, and after login, I redirect him to that page:

LoginController.php

```
// Se si stava tentando di accedere ad una pagina prima di effettuare la login, reinderizzo l'utente ad essa
    if ($request->session()->has("URL_PWD")) {
        return redirect($request->session()->pull("URL_PWD"));
    }
```

In local this code work right, but in my linux server host, it doesn't.

Login routes:

```
// Login
Route::group(["middleware" => "isAuth"], function() {
    Route::get("login", "LoginController@getLogin");
    Route::post("login", "LoginController@postLogin");
});
```

My site is in HTTPS, this could cause some problems with session?

Comment: do you want to redirect to previous page back if auth is failed?

Comment: What about `return redirect()->back()`. Is there a reason you're not using this?

Comment: Because, if I use it, the function post login, redirect me back to the get login route and my middleware "isAuth" check if user is authenticate, if yes, redirect him to main page

Answer (score 1):

Use the `back()` function. From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects):

> Sometimes you may wish to redirect the user to their previous
>   location, such as when a submitted form is invalid. You may do so by
>   using the global `back` helper function. Since this feature utilizes
>   the session, make sure the route calling the back function is using
>   the web middleware group or has all of the session middleware applied:

```
Route::post('user/profile', function () {
    // Validate the request...

    return back()->withInput();
});
```

Comment: If i use back(), it return to the login route, where the middleware "isAuth" checks if user is authenticate, if yes, I redirect him to main page: `Route::group(["middleware" => "isAuth"], function() {
        Route::get("login", "LoginController@getLogin");
        Route::post("login", "LoginController@postLogin");
    });`